# How to assign values inside a lambda expression

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

In Android, I was learning authentication in firebase. I want to store a Boolean value to a variable which is whether the task was successful or not. Here is my code:-

```
fun signIn(userEmail: String, userPassword: String): Boolean {
    var successful = false
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            successful = it.isSuccessful
            Log.d(TAG, "successful = $successful")
        }
    Log.d(TAG, "successful = $successful")
    return successful
}
```

When this method is invoked, the successful variable inside the higher-order function changes to true but it has no effect when it comes outside. Here is my log file:-

```
D/UserAuthentication: successful = true
D/UserAuthentication: successful = false
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner Log is called after your outer Log because the method `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is Asynchronous

Do something like this:

```
fun signIn(userEmail: String, userPassword: String, callback: (Task<AuthResult>) -> Unit) {
     mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            callback.invoke(it)
        }
}
```

Then call this function like this:

```
signIn("your_username", "your_password") {
    if(it.isSuccessfull){
         //Your login was successfull
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `callback: (Task<AuthResult>) -> Unit` ?

Comment: @NishantJalan I didn't really know the signature of the callback. If that works, yes it should. I will edit it.

Comment: Since `it` is an object of Task<AuthResult>, it parameter of the higher-order function should also be Task<AuthResult>... Thanks for the edit.